# counting up and then down a range in python

Tags: python

I am trying to program a standard snake draft, where team A pick, team B, team C, team C, team B, team A, ad nauseum.

If pick number 13 (or pick number x) just happened how can I figure which team picks next for n number of teams.

I have something like:

```
def slot(n,x):
    direction = 'down' if (int(x/n) & 1) else 'up'
    spot = (x % n) + 1
    slot = spot if direction == 'up' else ((n+1) - spot)
    return slot
```

I have feeling there is a simpler, more pythonic what than this solution. Anyone care to take a hack at it?

So I played around a little more. I am looking for the return of a single value, rather than the best way to count over a looped list.  The most literal answer might be:

```
def slot(n, x): # 0.15757 sec for 100,000x 
    number_range = range(1, n+1) + range(n,0, -1)
    index = x % (n*2)
    return number_range[index]
```

This creates a list [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1], figures out the index (e.g. 13 % (4*2) = 5), and then returns the index value from the list (e.g. 4). The longer the list, the slower the function.

We can use some logic to cut the list making in half. If we are counting up (i.e. `(int(x/n) & 1)` returns False), we get the obvious index value (x % n), else we subtract that value from n+1:

```
def slot(n, x): # 0.11982 sec for 100,000x 
    number_range = range(1, n+1) + range(n,0, -1)
    index = ((n-1) - (x % n)) if (int(x/n) & 1) else (x % n)
    return number_range[index]
```

Still avoiding a list altogether is fastest:

```
def slot(n, x): # 0.07275 sec for 100,000x
    spot = (x % n) + 1
    slot = ((n+1) - spot) if (int(x/n) & 1) else spot
    return slot
```

And if I hold the list as variable rather than spawning one:

```
number_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
def slot(n, x): # 0.03638 sec for 100,000x
    return number_list[x % (n*2)]
```

Comment: Should team number n, as well as team number 1, pick twice in a row at the turn?

Comment: yes. Team 1 and team n have two consecutive picks at the turn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use itertools [`cycle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) function:

```
from itertools import cycle
li = range(1, n+1) + range(n, 0, -1) # e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
it = cycle(li)

[next(it) for _ in xrange(10)] # [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Note: previously I had answered how to run up and down, as follows:

```
it = cycle(range(1, n+1) + range(n, 0, -1)) #e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Comment: order should be [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,1,2,...] .. so what else do I do with the cycle function?

Comment: In python3, the second line should be `li = [*range(1, n+1), *range(n, 0, -1)]`. This is because range() in python 3 does not return a list, like it does in python 2.  Likewise, `range` and `xrange` were merged in python3. For some reason no edits to this answer are being approved. Like

Answer (score 7):

Here's a generator that will fulfill what you want.

```
def draft(n):
    while True:
        for i in xrange(1,n+1):
            yield i
        for i in xrange(n,0,-1):
            yield i

>>> d = draft(3)
>>> [d.next() for _ in xrange(12)]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import chain, cycle

def cycle_up_and_down(first, last):
    up = xrange(first, last+1, 1)
    down = xrange(last, first-1, -1)
    return cycle(chain(up, down))

turns = cycle_up_and_down(1, 4)
print [next(turns) for n in xrange(10)] # [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of numbers that counts up, then down:

```
>>> [ -abs(5-i)+5 for i in range(0,10) ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Written out:

```
count_up_to = 5
for i in range( 0, count_up_to*2 ):
  the_number_you_care_about = -abs(count_up_to-i) + count_up_to
  # do stuff with the_number_you_care_about
```

Easier to read:

```
>>> list( range(0,5) ) + list( range( 5, 0, -1 ) )
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Written out:

```
count_up_to = 5
for i in list( range(0,5) ) + list( range(5, 0, -1) ):
  # i is the number you care about
```

Another way:

```
from itertools import chain
for i in chain( range(0,5), range(5,0,-1) ):
  # i is the number you care about
```